# Numpy matrix creation timing oddity

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

My application requires a starting matrix where each column is staggered-by-1 from the previous.  It will contain millions of complex numbers representing a signal, but a small example is:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

I tried two creation methods, one fast, one slow.  I don't understand why the fast matrix creation method causes subsequent calculations to run slowly, while the slow matrix creation results in faster running calculations.  The subroutine calcs() simply takes FFTs to offer minimal code to demonstrate the issue I see in my actual signal processing code.  A sample run yields:

```
python ex.py 
Slow Create, Fast Math
   57.90 ms, create
   36.79 ms, calcs()
   94.69 ms, total
Fast Create, Slow Math
   15.13 ms, create
  355.38 ms, calcs()
  370.50 ms, total
```

Code follows.  Any insight would be appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import time

N = 65536
Np = 64

# Random signal for demo.
x = np.random.randint(-50,50,N+Np) + 1j*np.random.randint(-50,50,N+Np)

def calcs(sig):
    np.fft.fft(sig)

print('Slow Create, Fast Math')
t0 = time.time()
X = np.zeros((N, Np), dtype=complex)
for col in range(Np):
    X[:,col] = x[col:col+N]
t1 = time.time()
calcs(X)
t2 = time.time()
print('  %6.2f ms, create' % (1e3 * (t1 - t0)))
print('  %6.2f ms, calcs()' % (1e3 * (t2 - t1)))
print('  %6.2f ms, total' % (1e3 * (t2 - t0)))

print('Fast Create, Slow Math')
t0 = time.time()
X = np.array([x[i:i+N] for i in range(Np)]).transpose()
t1 = time.time()
calcs(X)
t2 = time.time()
print('  %6.2f ms, create' % (1e3 * (t1 - t0)))
print('  %6.2f ms, calcs()' % (1e3 * (t2 - t1)))
print('  %6.2f ms, total' % (1e3 * (t2 - t0)))
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's being caused by your "fast creation" creating a transposed matrix.  That changes the underlying contiguity which either is slower in the underlying fourier transform implementation or results in a copy somewhere.

Comment: you can also try `X = np.empty((N, Np), dtype=complex)`. that might give some speed-ups

Comment: Please provide more information about your Python installation as well as version of Numpy. Also what operating system do you use and how did you install Numpy? I cannot reproduce your observation, for me both "calcs" use the same time (by the way, using [`time.process_time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time) is more accurate for timing code execution (unless you're really interested in wall time)).

Comment: user3483203, many thanks!  That is it.  When I create the matrix row by row, the "fast" now performs calculations in about the same amount time following the "slow" creation.

User a_guest, sorry for that oversight.  I'm running pytthon 3.7.10 on Ubuntu 21.04, on a machine with two AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

user3483203's comment, above, provides answer to the issue.  If I avoid the transpose by creating the matrix with:

```
X = np.array([x[i:i+Np] for i in range(N)], dtype=complex)
```

subsequent calcs() timing is as expected.  Thank you, user3483203!